# How can we inject dependency into angular factory using $inject?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, inject

I'm trying to define a constant and inject that into a factory. My Constant is defined as follows:

```
angular.module("ContactApp").constant("BaseApiURL", "http://localhost:31523/api/");
```

My factory is defined as:

```
angular.module("ContactApp").factory('CustomerService', CustomerService);

//CustomerService.$inject = ['BaseApiURL']; Giving Error when this line is active.

function CustomerService(BaseApiURL, $resource) {

    return $resource(BaseApiURL + 'Customers');
};
```

The above code is working, but don't I need to inject the constant as dependency into the factory method? I can inject the constant using the $inject into a controller but couldn't do that into the factory.

Comment: What is your problem with this approach?

Comment: as per my knowledge, We need to inject any service before using it in any controller, similary I was thinking I need to inject the constant before using it into the factory method, so I tried to inject it using CustomerService.$inject = ['BaseApiURL']; But then the code stopped working. I was looking for the explanation.

Comment: What error did you get..?

Comment: Did u just call `CustomerService.$inject = ['BaseApiURL'];`? May be in your case it should be `CustomerService.$inject = ['BaseApiURL','$resource'];`.

Answer (score 1):

In angular's dependency injection, if you don't do dependency annotation (like setting .$inject), angular will assume that the function parameter names are the names of the dependencies.

**But don't rely on this feature since it will cause problem when you attempt to minify your code.**

So the best practice should be do dependency annotation wherever there is dependency injection.

Btw u can set $inject in factory but maybe u should call `CustomerService.$inject = ['BaseApiURL','$resource'];` in your case.